# Dynamic SQL (T-Sql) returns varchar instead of float

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Apparently my T-Sql skills are a little rusty.
I have the following table type defined:

```
CREATE TYPE QualityControlData 
   AS TABLE
      ( SU float            -- Uniformity
      , ND float            -- Good
      , DIS float           -- Dissimilar
      , DBL float           -- Doubles
      , CS float            -- CS64
      , FM float            -- EmbeddedShell + Organic + Nonorganic
      , PHD float           -- PinHoles
      , SNB float           -- SplitBroken
      , OD float            -- OtherDefects
      , SHRV float          -- Shrivel
      , Gum float           -- GUM
      , BRNS float          -- BrownSpot
      , SD float            -- SeriousDamage
      , INS float           -- InsectInjury
      , MLD float           -- DMR
      , FR float            -- Frass
      , TK char(255)        -- MD4
      , EMY float);         -- Good + Dissimilar + doubles + chip + scratch + cs64 + split + broken + otherdefects
GO
```

I declare a variable of the table type:

```
Declare @TestData QualityControlData
```

I create and execute the following query:

```
Declare @GetQCValueCommand nvarchar(max)
set @GetQCValueCommand = 'select ' + @QCTestID + ' from @TestData'
EXEC @QCValue = sp_executesql @GetQCValueCommand, N'@TestData QualityControlData readonly',@TestData
```

`QCTestID` is equal to 'SU', so the query ends up looking like:

```
select SU from @TestData
```

The value of the `SU` column in the data table is float 0.2324422, the query returns a varchar and the `QCValue` is zero ('0').  I figured this out when the procedure crashed when it couldn't convert the returned value to float.  What am I missing?  Is this normal for T-Sql dynamic Sql and do I need to convert the data when selecting it or am I not understanding something?

Comment: Didn't know you could fill a variable with EXEC that way.  Did you declare @QCValue for that?  What type?  Also, can that query return more than 1 row?

Comment: @LukStorms the OP isn't. They are setting the value of the `RETURN` value from `sp_executesql` to `@QCValue`. It's a documented feature, and has been in SQL Server for as long as I can remember. Certainly since SQL 2008/2005, if not prior (I didn't work with prior versions): [Returning status codes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/return-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#b-returning-status-codes)

Comment: Oh gods, the injection problems in that @PrescottChartier !!! You have a far worse problem that what your initial question ever said you did. What you have there is a ***HUGE*** security concern just waiting to be exploited. You need to fix that; NOW.

Comment: What do you suppose would happen if someone ran these commands? `CREATE TABLE #T (qctestid int); EXEC [spUpdateTestTable] N'#T; CREATE LOGIN SU WITH PASSWORD = ''123abc!"''--', 1; EXEC [spUpdateTestTable] N'#T; ALTER SERVER ROLE sysadmin ADD MEMBER SU;--',1;`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`0` is correct, you're setting the value of `@QCValue` to the **`RETURN`** value of `sp_executesql` and `0` means success. From [RETURN (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/return-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#b-returning-status-codes):

> Unless documented otherwise, all system stored procedures return a value of 0. This indicates success and a nonzero value indicates failure.

If you want to output a scalar value you want to do the following:

```
DECLARE @QCTestID sysname = N'SU',
        @QCValue float;

DECLARE @GetQCValueCommand nvarchar(MAX);
SET @GetQCValueCommand = N'SELECT @QCValue = ' + QUOTENAME(@QCTestID) + N' FROM @TestData;'; --Safely quoted value
EXEC sp_executesql @GetQCValueCommand,
                   N'@TestData QualityControlData readonly, @QCValue float OUTPUT', --Added output parameter
                   @TestData,
                   @QCValue OUTPUT;--Added output parameter

SELECT @QCValue;
```

*Edit: also, the value previously returned wasn't  `varchar`, it was an `int`.*

Comment: Interesting, already figured out that it would need an OUTPUT variable. But not that the return status of sp_executesql can be captured.  +1

Comment: `sp_executesql` is still a Stored Procedure, as well as a Special Procedure, @LukStorms . So just like any of the other Special Procedures, it'll return `0` for success, and the error code in the event it fails. From the above linked document *"Unless documented otherwise, all system stored procedures return a value of 0. This indicates success and a nonzero value indicates failure."*

Comment: Changed my code to the answer above and I still get the error `Error converting data type varchar to float.`  When I change the definition of `@QCValue` to type `varchar(max)`, I do get the value of the data but it's a string.  I can work with that, but it's not what should be happening, no?

Comment: Nothing in the above outputs a string (`varchar`) @PrescottChartier . `@QCValue` is defined as a `float`. if you're getting a `varchar`, it's not from the code above.

Comment: As you can see, @PrescottChartier, the above does not generate an error: [DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=5e8edfa3f4c8320490b900aef5f5f915)

Comment: That is NOT what's happening, I used EXACTLY the same code as in the answer, I get NO error when `@QCValue` is a varchar (and I get the value I'm looking for) and an error when it's a float.  `@QCValue` is used no where else in the stored procedure.

Comment: If you're testing against `TK` that'll happen, @PrescottChartier, you didn't define that column as a float. Otherwise no, that won't happen. YOu'll need to replicate and show the problem, as this *does* work.

Comment: I use a different SQL statement for the TK value, `@QCValue1` defined as `varchar(max)`.

Comment: Then you need to show me how you get the error, as the code I have supplied *works*, @PrescottChartier .

Comment: At @PrescottChartier I have seen a lot. You ***need*** to learn about SQL injection. It's 2019 and SQL Injection should have been dead in the entire industry years ago. There is no excuse for such a security flawed procedure. [Little Bobby Tables](https://xkcd.com/327/)

Comment: It's **because** of your injection issues that you *have* the problem @PrescottChartier  . You have the expression `'...', ' + @QCValue + ', ''QCIFY'''` as `@QCValue` is a `float` that has a **higher** datatype precedence than a `varchar`, your dynamic statement must be converted to a float. and `'insert into ...'` is **not** a `float`. Fix the injection, fix the conversion error.

Comment: You also have `Print '@QCValue = ' + @QCValue` , @PrescottChartier , which requires the RDBMS to implicitly cast the `varchar` value `'@QCValue = '` to a `float`; which again, is impossible.